# abuse of the Peer Pressure Badge?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, badges

wouldn't it be abuse of the Peer Pressure Badge to deliberately post a silly question that's bound to get bad reviews?  Or is that ok as bronze badges are for trying out things?

Comment: In short, yes. It would be abuse, please don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'd rather you didn't; the intent is to encourage you to delete bad posts, not to post more of them. See [Flaw in the Peer Pressure badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126679/flaw-in-the-the-peer-pressure-badge), [Badges should reward positive behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107628/badges-should-reward-positive-behavior)

Comment: What if the posts aren't bad, but they are deleted because you pissed people off for valid reasons? IMO the good way to get the badge is basically to Jesus {minor key symbol which should exist but doesn't appear to be available on this forum in comments...}. So, Jesus minor...